# Create 2D grid from vector data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, plot, grid

I am trying to create a 2-D grid from a vector. 
So, for example I have:

```
x = 1:1:10;
z = 2:2:20;
```

Now, I want to create a grid which has x on both side of the grid cell and z as grid cell value.
I tried doing it as :

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x, x);
newZ = griddata(x, x ,z, X, Y);
```

But this gives me error:

> The underlying triangulation is empty - the points may be
>   collinear.

Need help solving this.

Comment: What do you mean by "z as grid cell value" since z is a vector? Can you please put an example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

In a high level, `griddata()` takes a 2d surface with variable z-value at each point as the first part of the input, and the query points as the second part of the input. To be more specific, when we look into the definition of the function:

```
vq = griddata(x,y,v,xq,yq)
```

`x` and `y` specifies the range of x and y values, `v` is like z-value in a plane, and `xq` and `yq` together are query points. Here, `v` (in your case, `z`) is expected to be a 2d matrix, to be more specific, the size of `v` is `[length(x), length(y)]`, whereas in your case, you put `z` as a vector. Matlab generates the warning since the size doesn't match.

For your reference: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html?refresh=true